# callback function with setInterval without any argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following script which does an ajax call once and after that it does ajax call to another url after every second. I implemented the following code but I think I am not able to fix this callback issue to run the second function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ajaxSingleCall(function(){
        ajaxCalls();
    });
});

function ajaxSingleCall(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/matchDataOdds",
        dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            data.forEach(addOddsCanvas);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("Ajax failed to fetch data");
        });
}

function ajaxCalls(){
    setInterval(runner, 1000);
}

function runner() {
    // run your ajax call here
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/matchData",
    dataType: 'json'
    })
        .done(function(data) {
            liveFeed(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("Ajax failed to fetch data");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling it from inside `ajaxSingleCall()` instead. I've edited your code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ajaxSingleCall();
});

function ajaxSingleCall(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/matchDataOdds",
        dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            data.forEach(addOddsCanvas);
            ajaxCalls(); // <-- here
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("Ajax failed to fetch data");
        });
}

function ajaxCalls(){
    setInterval(runner, 1000);
}

function runner() {
    // run your ajax call here
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/matchData",
    dataType: 'json'
    })
        .done(function(data) {
            liveFeed(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("Ajax failed to fetch data");
        });
}
```

Comment: But still uses setInterval - not recommended with AJAX

Comment: Glad I could help @VanshajBehl. Remember to accept my answer if it helped you solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend to NOT use setInterval with AJAX. If the server is slow to return, you may start hammering the server with calls upon calls. If you use the done or complete, the server has returned as fast as it could.

Instead put the runner in the done of ajaxSingleCall and then use setTimeout in the done of runner

Note: Your code failed because you did not execute the passed callback in ajaxSingleCall

```js
$(function() {
  ajaxSingleCall(); // not taking any parameters anyway...
});

function ajaxSingleCall() {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/matchDataOdds",
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      data.forEach(addOddsCanvas);
      runner();
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("Ajax failed to fetch data");
    });
}

function runner() {
  // run your ajax call here
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/matchData",
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      liveFeed(data);
      setTimeout(runner, 1000);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("Ajax failed to fetch data");
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for advice but what is reason for setTimeout over setInterval?

Comment: If the server takes more than 1 second to return, you will start hammering it - issuing a second call while it is busy doing the first, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a callback function into `ajaxSingleCall`, but it doesn't accept any parameters. You have to actually use the function that's passed. It won't be called automatically:

```
function ajaxSingleCall(callback){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/matchDataOdds",
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        data.forEach(addOddsCanvas);
        callback();
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("Ajax failed to fetch data");
    });
}
```

Comment: this will solve the immediate issue but not handle server overload

Answer (score 0):

ajaxCalls() will not get called because ajaxSingleCall function does not take any parameter.